# Starting Class or Method Names with Numbers, Why Not?

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, naming

I recently was quickly shortening some method names in a JavaScript file and ran into a problem when I converted one method name:

Before:

```js
RefreshSevenDayGrid(){
    // some stuff
}
```

After:

```js
7Day() {    
    // some stuff
}
```

I quickly discovered that the javascript no longer worked. I heard from several people that numbers should never be used for method or class names. Is there ever an exception to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides what Jeffrey Hantin said, there are numeric constants such as

```
3e7  // 3x10^7
40L  // C, C++, etc for a long integer
0x88 // hexadecimal
```

The general convention for identifiers which is used widely in most languages, is `[S except for 0-9][S]*` where S is some set of valid characters (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, sometimes _, $, or -) -- so the first character can't be a digit but the rest can.

Answer (score 7):

It tends to cause fits for language parsers.  It sees a leading digit, so expects to begin reading a numeric literal, then barfs when it sees a letter.  Even the algebraic convention is that a number to the left of a letter is a separate numeric literal with the space omitted, so *7x* would be seen as two tokens.